# Javascript TypeError: variable is undefined

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

presently I am working on a Ruby on Rails app, and I am trying to get the below JS to work with the app.  The first issue I came across was turbolinks 5.0 was preventing the page from loading the JS on initial load, and I would have to refresh the page in order to load the below JS.  I did some googling, and came across [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18770589/708807), but I can't seem to get the JS to run properly without throwing an error.  Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

**orders.js**

```
console.log('inside orders.js');

$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
// Your JS here
var payment;

jQuery(function() {
  Stripe.setPublishableKey($('meta[name="stripe-key"]').attr('content'));
  return payment.setupForm();
});

payment = {
  setupForm: function() {
    return $('#new_order').submit(function() {
      $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', true);
      Stripe.card.createToken($('#new_order'), payment.handleStripeResponse);
      return false;
    });
  },
  handleStripeResponse: function(status, response) {
    if (status === 200) {

      // return alert(response.id);
      $('#new_order').append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(response.id));
      return $('#new_order')[0].submit();

    } else {

      // return alert(response.error.message);
      return $('#stripe_error').text(response.error.message).show();

    }
  }
};
});
```

Comment: `"without throwing an error"` - What error?  Which line throws the error?  What are the runtime values when that happens?

Comment: Jquery(function(){return "sth"}); is nonsense

Comment: Without a lot of details I would say it's because you are doing jQuery on ready with `$` and then check again if jQuery is ready with `jQuery`, basically calling on ready twice with 2 different values `$` vs `jQuery`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comment mentioned above, the issue was related to where the `jQuery` statement was located in the JS.  I restructured the JS to look like the following, and everything appears to be working now.

**orders.js**

```
console.log('inside orders.js');

$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
// Your JS here
var payment;

payment = {
  setupForm: function() {
    return $('#new_order').submit(function() {
      $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', true);
      Stripe.card.createToken($('#new_order'), payment.handleStripeResponse);
      return false;
    });
  },

  handleStripeResponse: function(status, response) {
    if (status === 200) {

      // return alert(response.id);
      $('#new_order').append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(response.id));
      return $('#new_order')[0].submit();

    } else {

      // return alert(response.error.message);
      return $('#stripe_error').text(response.error.message).show();

    }
  }
};

jQuery(function() {
  Stripe.setPublishableKey($('meta[name="stripe-key"]').attr('content'));
  return payment.setupForm();
});
});
```